# iOS: How to add more views after viewDidLoad

Tags: ios, xcode, uiviewcontroller

I am new to IOS programming. I am starting from the basic application created by XCode 4.3 (SingleView application).
Continuing from my above question, I was able to add Views programmaticaly to the main ViewController in the Appdelegate but If I want to do the same after the view has loaded (inside viewDidLoad), I am facing the trouble. I tried using the same logic of adding subviews but I am not sure if the view needs a refresh after adding inside 'viewDidLoad'

My views are very simple, here is the code

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{

[super viewDidLoad];
UIBUtton *btn = [UIBUtton] alloc] initWithFrame:CGRect(10,10,50,50)];
[self.view addSubView:btn];
[self.view setNeedsDsiplay];
}
```

Can someone please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not instantiating the `UIButton` correctly. You should use `buttonWithType:` method.

For example:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

[super viewDidLoad];

UIButton * btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];

[btn setFrame:CGRectMake(10.0, 10.0, 50.0, 50.0)];

[[self view] addSubview:btn];

}
```

Comment: Thanks!! Yes that worked, the problem was in instantiating UIBUtton.

Answer (score -1):

You have placed square brackets at wrong places. Probably you are new to Objective-C. You should pay more attention to learning syntax before creating UI based apps.

```
UIBUtton *btn = [UIBUtton] alloc] initWithFrame:CGRect(10,10,50,50)];
```

Should be:

```
UIBUtton *btn = [[UIBUtton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRect(10,10,50,50)];
```

Also

```
[self.view setNeedsDsiplay];
```

is not needed.